# How to read input.date/input.choice/ input.text value from adaptive card which uses action.showcard in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

[image]

I am using the above attached adaptive card which uses input.date,input.choice which is action.showcard.
How to read the values from the above card for further validation using Node.js.
Am using this adaptive card in Microsoft Teams channel.

Currently I tried Using context.activity.value/context.activity.value.userText which returns undefined in onMessage.

Comment: Have you read this? https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: Thanks a lot@KyleDelaney

Comment: Does that mean you've resolved your issue? What was the solution?

Comment: Are you still working on this?